# Change text file on runtime in resource.rc winapi c++

Tags: c++, winapi, text, replace, resources

I would like to read from file in resource file. That's ok like so:

`char LineBuffer[255];
    HRSRC hRes = FindResource(0, MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID_TEXT_FILE), "0");
    if(hRes != NULL)
    {
        HGLOBAL hData = LoadResource(0, hRes);
        if(hData != NULL)
        {
            sprintf(LineBuffer, "%s", LockResource(hData));
        }
    }`

But I want to change the text in the txt file stored in resource. I have read something about it and everyone uses `BeginUpdateResource(); UpdateResource(); EndUpdateResource();` but I don't get it. Any help would be appreciated :) A code snippet would be awesome. Thanks in advance ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A running process cannot alter its own resources.  You have to use a separate application to update the resources of the main application while it is not running.  Only then can you use `(Begin/End)UpdateResource()`.

Comment: Well, I don't really think so...When I run the program and open it in Visual Studio resource editor, I can edit all files in the application even during runtime. Even when I downloaded ResourceHacker, I was able to edit the application itself during runtime. So there must be some way to do that, right?

Comment: [Per MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648030.aspx): "An application must be able to obtain write-access to this file; the file referenced by pFileName cannot be currently executing."

Comment: @Petr MSDN: Ok, thank you. I thought, that when MVS can write to the file during runtime, the application should be able to write to itself as well, but I was mistaken, MVS actually create a temp file and change that. So I will have to do it another way. Problem solved.